# Have top right button click be recognized in presentational component using react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My app scenes use a container component which calls a presentational component.

I can create the top right button within the container component like this:

```
static right = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => buttonPressed()}>
      <Text style={styles.rightButtonText}>Done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Now I am trying to have the top right button click be recognized by the presentational component (so it can save data).

I can communicate between the two by sending a function as a prop from the container component to the presentational component. And when that is called from the presentational component, it is called in the container component.

But I have found no way to make the `static right` function in the container component *hear* the click in the presentational component (to then take the appropriate action).

I tried [these two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133675/4407512) along with several others (including Action.refresh) but none work. I thought of using state, but I cannot access `state` or `this.` if I am using a static function. But removing `static` makes the button disappear altogether.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar challenge in the past. The way I tackled was as follows (taken (*mostly*) directly from the codebase). Note that they are similar methods to the examples you provided, but perhaps this makes sense to you.

**• Container component**

Has an `updateAccount` function which handles the business logic. This is passed into the *presentational component* as a `prop`.

**• Presentational component**

Highlighting 2x specific functions from the presentational component:

---

`handleChange`

- On text input change, this function is triggered and data from the input is updated in state
- When this is called, we know that the form has changed, so we want to show a 'save' button in the (react-native-router-flux) Navbar (which on tap, should trigger our container's `updateAccount`). So we call `toggleSaveButton`:

  ```
  handleChange = (name, val) => {
      this.setState({ [name]: val, formChanged: true }, this.toggleSaveButton);
  }
  ```

---

`toggleSaveButton`

- If `this.state.formChanged` is true, the form has changed so add the save button for the user to tap, otherwise hide it (eg. I might hide on form submit success)

  ```
  toggleSaveButton = () => {
    const config = this.state.formChanged
      ? { rightTitle: 'Save', onRight: () => this.props.updateAccount(this.state) }
      : { rightTitle: '', onRight: () => {} };

    Actions.refresh(config);
  };
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much mcnamee, this is exactly what I needed. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I am not able to implement with image change :(